# What does the fieldID in Hive SerDe interface StructField stands for?

Tags: java, hive, hive-serde

In order to implement a SerDe I use StructField implementation.

I've upgraded the hive version and now the interface has the getFieldID method.

What does this method stands for? Any special guidance for the implementation of it?